# How can I string number convert in date in XSLT format, like the JavaScript date function?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

How can I convert a string number into date format in XSLT?

My code is

```
<insertdate>1494489190000</insertdate>
```

I have found several things in Google, but I did not find any good solution. What is the best solution for this?

Like this in JavaScript:

```
new Date(1494489190000)
Thu May 11 2017 13:23:10 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

But how can I do it in XSLT?

Comment: There are three different versions of XSLT, only XSLT 2 and 3 have support for `xs:date` and `xs:dateTime` and have functions like `format-date` or `format-dateTime`. So first find out or decide whether you use an XSLT 2 or 3 processor.

Comment: xslt 3 i used in my code

Answer (score 0):

I think in JavaScript the `Date` constructor takes the milliseconds since 1970-01-01, for XSLT/XPath 2 and later `xs:date` or `xs:dateTime` you need to take that date and add the value as a duration:

```
  <xsl:param name="date-time-value" as="xs:integer" select="1494489190000"/>

  <xsl:variable name="dateTime" as="xs:dateTime"
    select="xs:dateTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00') + xs:dayTimeDuration('PT' || $date-time-value div 1000 || 'S')"/>
```

Different output formats are possible using `format-date` or `format-dateTime`, start with the examples in http://www.datypic.com/books/xquery/chapter20.html, then look at the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-format-dateTime, https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#rules-for-datetime-formatting or ask a specific question on what you what achieve.